# desc table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to see the definition of a table in SQL Server.

Running this query from SQLPro for MSSQL is OK

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.[ATRESMEDIA Resource Time Registr_];
```

but when I run this one

```
exec sp_columns dbo.[ATRESMEDIA Resource Time Registr_];
```

I got this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1.
Incorrect syntax near '.'. (Line 3)
```

Comment: Cause this is ought to be a string argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont use schema `dbo`.

```
exec sp_columns [ATRESMEDIA Resource Time Registr_];
```

why? because, following are the parameters accepted by sp_columns stored proc:

> sp_columns [ @table_name = ] object
>              [ , [ @table_owner = ] owner ]
>              [ , [ @table_qualifier = ] qualifier ]
>              [ , [ @column_name = ] column ]
>              [ , [ @ODBCVer = ] ODBCVer ]

source: [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql)

**update:**
Martin's explanation as in comment:

Strings in SQL Server are delimited by single quotes - as a parameter to a stored proc in very limited circumstances it will allow you to skip the quotes but the dot breaks that. `exec sp_columns 'dbo.[ATRESMEDIA Resource Time Registr_]';` wouldn't give the syntax error - but that wouldn't be what the proc expects anyway as the schema would need to be the second param

Comment: This isn't the correct explanation of the behaviour

Comment: stored proc accepts string.`dbo.` is not a string, hence not accepted. Isn't it right? If not, please can you add your explanation in my answer or comment it here?

Comment: yes because strings in SQL Server are delimited by single quotes - as a parameter to a stored proc in very limited circumstances it will allow you to skip the quotes but the dot breaks that.  `exec sp_columns 'dbo.[ATRESMEDIA Resource Time Registr_]';` wouldn't give the syntax error - but as you point out that wouldn't be what the proc expects anyway as the schema would need to be the second param

Comment: I'll append your explanation in my answer. I meant the same, couldn't put in words though :)

Answer (score 0):

select the table name in the query window

and press the below key combination

Alt +F1 or
Alt+Fn+F1 will bring the table definition